# Wifi hotspot connecting to multiple wifi sources

Tags: wifi, backup

I'm looking for wifi hotspot. this hotspot is used to connect my cameras.

this hotspot is connected to my home wifi (like a wifi extender)

This hotspot can connect to my home wifi, and if home wifi is OFF it can connect to backup wifi

so my cameras are always connected to wifi. because my cameras only connect to one wifi (not possibility to dynamically switch wifi)

Comment: I guess you need to do your magic using a switch (or router), so that the wifi access point (hotspot) doesnt know any different.

Comment: I think you'd be better off setting up a WAN fallback on your router, rather than having a separate device just for your cameras; you'd probably run into all sorts of issues if you try to have something other than your router dynamically switch network assignments. What router do you have currently, and what would your budget/space constraints be for a new one?